# Unity Adding Downwards Force to object based on global position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**I am trying to add force to a sphere object** 
In this instance, the object is a basketball and I want to simulate dribbling a ball.
The basketball is rotating as it rolls around and I would like to make it so that you can apply downwards force to it on any rotation making it go only up or down without the force making the ball move on the x or z axis.

The Code I have for it so far

```
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                Pickupable p = hit.collider.GetComponent<Pickupable>();
                if (p != null)
                {
                    hit.collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddRelativeForce( p.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.down * 5),  ForceMode.Impulse);
                }
            }
```

Much Appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think `Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition` will help. [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition.html)

Comment: Yeah I had tried that but it was adding torque to the object which ofcourse I didn't want.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem(s)

Well as the name suggests [`AddForceRelative`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce.html)

> Adds a force to the rigidbody relative to its coordinate system.

so taking its orientation and scale into account.

Now what you are doing using [`Transform.TransformDirection`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformDirection.html) is converting the `Vector3.down` from **local** into **world** space.

So your code

```
hit.collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddRelativeForce(p.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.down * 5),  ForceMode.Impulse);
```

basically equals writing

```
hit.collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddRelativeForce(p.transform.up * -1),  ForceMode.Impulse);
```

which is of course not what you want for two reasons

- now you are using the **world space** vector `transform.up` as if it would be a **local** vector.
- you are applying the `* 5` to the vector given to the `Transform.Direction` but the returned vector is always **normalized** (magnitude = 1) so the factor is completely lost (except the sign).

---

#### Solution A

If you want a **global** downwards force what about not using a relative but a global force via the "normal" [`AddForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html)

```
hit.collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.down * 5, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

---

#### Option B

**If** you really want to use `AddForceRelative` you need to give it a vector in **local space**.

So you would rather use [`Transform.InverseTransformDirection`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformDirection.html)

> Transforms a direction from **world** space to **local** space.

which then you can use as a local vector in

```
hit.collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddRelativeForce( p.transform.InverseTransformDirection(Vector3.down) * 5,  ForceMode.Impulse)
```

again of course moving the multiplication with `* 5` to the returned vector.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. I used solution A and it worked right away. I think for learning, I'll definitely need to futher my understanding of 3d physics. Much Appreciated!